# Pytube : How to add the parameters for function progress_Check

Tags: python, pytube

```
def progress_Check(stream = None, chunk = None, file_handle = None, remaining = None):
    global file_size
    #Gets the percentage of the file that has been downloaded.
    percent = (100*(file_size-remaining))/file_size
    print("{:00.0f}% downloaded".format(percent))
```

When calling the above function for returning download percentage from

```
yt = YouTube(link,on_progress_callback=progress_Check)
```

**But I'm getting an error like can't subtract integer and None, So What are the function parameters/how to get them ?**

Any Idea ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`progress_Check` requires only 3 arguments: `stream`, `chunk`, and `remaining`

since only 3 arguments are needed, the 4th one isn't assigned to anything, therefore `remaining` would be set to `None` and would result in the error during the calculation

you also don't need to set each argument's default as `None` since those would get overriden anyways

here's the fixed code:

```
def progress_Check(stream, chunk, remaining):
    global file_size
    #Gets the percentage of the file that has been downloaded.
    percent = (100 * (file_size - remaining)) / file_size
    print("{:00.0f}% downloaded".format(percent))
```

Comment: Thanks Bro, That worked.
But it gives output only 100 % (When downloading is completed) and don't give any output during downloading. How to Solve it ?

Comment: that just means the download is really fast, it would show lower percentages if the download takes more time